# Difference between printing out value with for loop and simple variable input

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

What is the difference between simply printing out 'a' and looping it as illustrated by the example

CODE 1:

```
a = ['banana','apple','microsoft']

print(a)


['banana', 'apple', 'microsoft']
```

CODE 2:

```
for i in a:
    print(i)


banana
apple
microsoft
```

Comment: Well, the first one prints the whole list at once, while the second one prints every item of the list in one separate line.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code prints an list object. Python then picks the notation

```
['banana', 'apple', 'microsoft']
```

to represent the list one line. It also displays brackets to indicate that the objects within the list are strings. The list can even contain a mixture of types.

In your second piece of code you request a seperate line for every element in this list.
No square brackets are displayed as the list itself is never printed, it was just carrying the content before it was printed.